# Suppose $Hf∩Hg$ is non-empty. Prove that $Hf=Hg$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $H f = Hg$ if and only if $fg^-1 ∈ H$, but I'm not quite sure how to implement this to answer the question.

Comment: You're looking for a proof that cosets of $H\lhd G$ partition $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $x \in Hf\cap Hg$ then 
$$x=h_1f=h_2g$$

Deduce from here that 
$$f=h_1^{-1}h_2g \\
g=h_2^{-1}h_1f$$

From here you can easily deduce that $Hf \subseteq Hg$ and $Hg \subseteq Hf$.

Comment: Would this be correct?

suppose f ∈ Hg,then f =hg and g = h^-1f
claim that for some k ∈H, kf ∈Hf, then we have khg ∈Kg, where kh ∈ H, 
therefore kf ∈ Hf∩Hg

using the same argument in reverse for Kg∈ Hg and showing that its in Hf

I'm not sure whether this solution is valid, can someone correct me if this is in fact not valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $fg^{-1}\in H$, then $Hfg^{-1}=H$, hence …